# Modernize a compiler, late switch of generation-paradigm

Tags: source-code, paradigms, code-generation

Have been hired to modernize an old binary compiler that has been forgotten since a few years by people who have died already.

The compiler has

- a parser,
- an objectmodel and
- a generator of bytecode.

The main problem is now that the generation-part built the binary from top to bottom in one step.

```
while linkage
  while variables
    while read/write-lock
      while linkage
        while variables2
          while register2
            do write-header
        while variables3
          while range-check
             do write-introspection-info
      while linkage
        while variables3
          do reserve-memory
      while linkage
        while variables4
          do initialize
      while linkage
        while variables5
          do increase-stackcount (for later use)
```

As you can see we have repeating loops for a objectmodel that not has been changed meanwhile.

To reduce the loops (by keep the functionality), I need to buffer the results of the loops and buffers to write into first ... :

```
while linkage
  while variables
    do write-header > buffer 1
    do write-introspection-info > buffer 2
    do reserve-memory > buffer 3
    do initialize > buffer 4
    do incrementstackcount > buffer 5
```

... and combine it in a new phase of the generation-process like this:

```
do write buffers 1-5
```

Now the problem: Its dangerous work without practical results.

Any suggestions for a safe paradigm in this process?

Comment: Shall I focus on one buffer and all loops, or one loop and all buffers?

Answer (score 1):

> Now the problem: Its dangerous work without practical results.

That's a problem all right.

You want someone to pay you [a lot] of money to produce little, if any, practical benefit?

Why is this change even *necessary*?
Sure, it's a mite inefficient but are we talking *seconds* of overhead or *hours*? (Or days?)

If you are going to do this, then you **MUST** write [exhaustive] Tests before you start.  The output that ensues after your change absolutely must be the same as what was generated before, or any differences must be explainable.

Comment: Do not disturb me with logic. My luck, there are many good tests very everything and takes hours. After this review i need to inproove the functionality and performance. Everything for a dead language.

Answer (score 0):

Start with whichever seems (1. easier , 2. more likely to be low Order (O(N) not O(N^3)). Let us say that one loop and all buffers is easier to start with, do some of this development and testing as described below, and if the code generator rewrite gets too hard, try the other way ( one buffer and all loops).

You want to change a (complicated) thing and be sure the thing still does what the old thing did.

To restate your problem: You are trying to prove that compilation with the new compiler generates the same code as the old compiler, but faster ?

This is a testing problem.

- You already have a "known good" compiler for your target language ( the old compiler)

So the simplest test is a AUTOMATIC compilation of hello world by the old compiler and the new one, then compare the results.

**The reason to make the test automatic is that you are going to run this test every time you think the new code generator works.**

- You will probably need to disassemble the resulting binaries then compare to make finding issues easier.
- You will also probably need to create a "smart comparison" for output disassembly that does not care if thing you don't care about in the output files change. For example, order of variables changes,

Make the mechanism for doing this totally scriptable or automatic. 
  - You can test the test system by using the old compiler against itself.
  - And you need to do this to be sure that builds with the old compiler  are reproducible, *and if not, by what do they change*

If you can run all of this on large modern machine you can generate your remaining test vectors by going to a good fuzzer like American Fuzzy Lop.

- Test vectors are the inputs that you test your new compiler on. Your old compiler will of course serve as your transformation from source to expected test output.

Otherwise you will need sample programs to test with. The existing codebase that they want to support would be a sensible sample set.